# SQL Query: Modify Next Row Based On Current Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012.

The table I'm working with is shown below, along with code for the query. When I find ReasonString_S = 'Fault Reset' I would like to add that rows DurationMinutes_D to the next row and delete the current row.

I think a case when statement would work but I kept getting syntax issues and I'm fairly new to sql queries.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EntryDate_T) AS Row, e.equip_name, 
ReasonString_S, DurationMinutes_D, rt.Name_S ProcStateString, EntryDate_T 
into #temptable
from AT_PM_PlantStateEvent pse
inner join EQUIPMENT e on pse.OwnerKey_I = e.equip_key
inner join dbo.AT_PM_ReasonTree rt on pse.ReasonKey_64 = rt.atr_key
where EntryDate_T >= @jobstart and EntryDate_T < @jobend
and rt.Name_S <> 'Running'
and e.equip_name = @mach
```

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it's sql server, it's not mysql !

Comment: @DanielE. maybe he means its HIS sql?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question. What do you mean my "Delete the current row" for example? Do you actually mean you want to do a `DELETE` statement? Images don't help with SQL questions, I'm afraid; We can't run a SQL statement against an image of data. We need DDL and Consumable sample data; expected output is also very important. Have a look at [How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: in the image provided on line 16 is a "fault reset". Do you want to add the DurationMinutes_D on row 16 to row 17 and then remove row 16?

Comment: You have provide no keys into the AT_PM_PlantStateEvent table, how do you identify which record should be updated, Entry_Date, or is that query in natural order of the AT_PM_PlantStateEvent  table where the ROW_NUMBER would apply?

Comment: When I say delete I meant that I wanted to remove the row from the view that I'm generating. So I would not want the 'Fault Reset' row. @Cool_Br33ze that is correct.

Comment: @RossBush I'm generating a view that will then be used to create a chart on report builder. I'm not trying to updated the actual data base.

Comment: My bad, I thought you meant update the table and delete from the table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `Row` is your identity column if not then don't hesitate to create or use another existing one. It has many benefits as it's very useful in your case you can perform the desired operation with the help of that simply using `JOIN` as below:

```
create table #test(rowNum int identity(1,1), 
                   ReasonString_S varchar(50), 
                   DurationMinutes_D float)
insert into #test values
('Model1',0.34),
('Model2',0.35),
('Model3',0.36)
```

**DATA**:

```
rowNum  ReasonString_S  DurationMinutes_D
-----------------------------------------
1       Model1          0.34
2       Model2          0.35
3       Model3          0.36

update t set t.ReasonString_S = u.DurationMinutes_D
from #test t
left join #test u on u.rowNum = t.rowNum+1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
rowNum  ReasonString_S  DurationMinutes_D
-----------------------------------------
1       0.35            0.34
2       0.36            0.35
3       NULL            0.36
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general answer. To update a row based on the value in the next row, you should use the LEAD function. First you need to identify which column you want to sort by in order to determine which row is the next row. LEAD lets you get the value of a particular column from the next row. If you write a subquery using the LEAD function (which can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clause), you can update by joining to the subquery.

Conversely, to update a row based on the value in the previous row, you'd use the LAG function.

Here's an example:

```
declare @t1 table (id int, val varchar(10))

insert into @t1 values (1, 'val1')
insert into @t1 values (2, 'val2')
insert into @t1 values (3, 'val3')

update @t1 set val = sq.next_row_val
from @t1 t1
inner join (
    select t1.id, LEAD(t1.val) over (order by t1.id) as next_row_val
    from @t1 t1
)sq on t1.id = sq.id

select * from @t1

id  val
1   val2
2   val3
3   NULL
```